# php route with array function and database

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
    include("contact.php"); 
}
else if(isset($_GET['blog'])){
    include("blog.php"); 
}
else if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
    include("contact.php"); 
}
else if(isset($_GET['404'])){
    include("404.php"); 
}
?>
<?php
    include('admin/db.php'); 
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        else if(isset($_GET['<?php echo $row['url'];'])){
            include("new.php");
        }
    }
?>
<?php
else{
    include("index.php");
} 
?>
```

Here I can take url value from db. All db urls goto one page(new.php).
Is that possible?
I have fetch the else if condition in while loop.

Comment: Why else if? Why not just if? else if only works if it's attached to an if.

Comment: Also, you can just do `$_GET[$row['url']]` No need for to echo it.

Comment: If I'm using if conditions means, have a lot of check's. It takes time and also i have checked with if also not working properly.

Comment: Sorry. I meant in the while loop.

Comment: After using $_GET[$row['url']], Same issue continued "syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)"

Comment: Try using `if(isset($_GET[$row['url']])){` and see what happens.

Comment: It's working. But, if i have 100 urls in my table means, It takes more time to load for all if conditions and also I can't use else conditions here.

Comment: Are you asking for a more efficient way to do this, then?

Comment: Yes right. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Can you show your URL format from where you are getting `$_GET` ??

Comment: url columns have some text variable like cat, dog. If user type "index.php?dog" in address bar means it goes to new.php

Comment: @AzasoftSolutions Ah, okay. You may want to indicate this in your question. There are no other ways that I'm aware of, but if you add this to the question, others might have a better way.

Comment: `isset()` is not how you search for a substring.  Please improve your question by providing realistic input data, table data, and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
else if(isset($_GET['404'])){
    include("404.php"); 
}
else
{
    include('admin/db.php'); 
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        if(isset($_GET[$row['url']])){
            include("new.php");

            // When the URL is hit, no more work need to do.
            return;
        }
    }

    // If no URL is matched, the code goes to here.
    include("index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 $flag=0; // Set a flag for $GET['url']. If isset $_GET[$row['url'] then flag assign to 1 and loop beark.
    include('admin/db.php'); 
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        if(isset($_GET[$row['url']])){
            include("new.php");
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
   // If flag value is 0 then execute this code block 
    if($flag==0){
        if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
            include("contact.php"); 
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['blog'])){
            include("blog.php"); 
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['contact'])){
            include("contact.php"); 
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['404'])){
            include("404.php"); 
        }
        else{
            include("index.php");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: _Try this_/code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I've partially simplified this to avoid a multitude of elseifs.

A URL like `example.com/path/to/file.php?contact&blog`, would include the file `blog.php` (here blog occurs after contact).  If db routes are matched they map to `new.php`.

Here the `$db_routes` array is just an array of your database rows.

```
<?php
$routes =
[
    'contact',
    'blog',
    '404'
];

$db_routes =
[
    [
        'route' => 'hello',
        'content' => 'hello earth.'
    ],
    [
        'route' => 'bye',
        'content' => 'Goodbye.'
    ]
];
foreach($routes as $route) {
    if(isset($_GET[$route]))
        $file = $route . '.php';
}

foreach($db_routes as $route) {
    if(isset($_GET[$route['route']]))
        $file = 'new.php';
}

include $file ?? 'index.php';
```

But you'd probably not want to hit the database unnecessarily if your blog or contact route is matched first.

I'd have thought that also that a non-matching route, would lead to a 404.  Rather than having a url that looks something like `example.com/path/to/file.php?404` lead to it.  A 404 should also be served with the appropriate HTTP response code.

Perhaps a URL with no GET parameters should map to index.php, rather than your existing method that maps a non matching route to index.php (a 404 is more appropriate here).

But... also note that using GET keys to match a route will complicate any other usage of GET parameters - as there is potential of a name(space) clash.  Do you really want your URLs to look like this?